# Cmake shows "Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!" with Igraph package

Tags: c++, cmake, igraph, vcpkg

I wanted to import **igraph** into my C++ project. However, the output of my terminal shows error as below:

My command:

**PS C:\Users\Pei\OneDrive\文件\CppExercise\Example\build>cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="C:\Users\Desktop\GitHub\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake"**

Output:

```
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22000.0 to target Windows 10.0.22621.
CMake Error at C:/Users/Pei/Desktop/GitHub/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:853 (_find_package):
By not providing "Findigraph.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "igraph", but
CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "igraph" with any
of the following names:

igraphConfig.cmake
igraph-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "igraph" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "igraph_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "igraph"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Here's what I've done:

1. First I downloaded the package by using **vcpkg**, and here's output after I type **./vcpkg list igraph**:

```
PS C:\Users\Desktop\GitHub\vcpkg>./vcpkg list igraph
igraph:x86-windows 0.10.4 igraph is a C library for network analysis and g…
igraph[graphml]:x86-windows Support for reading GraphML files
```

2. Then, I made a **CMakeLists.txt** file in my project with below commands:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(${igraph_test})

find_package(igraph REQUIRED)

add_executable(${igraph_test} ${main}.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${igraph_test} PUBLIC igraph::igraph)
```

3. I commanded in VScode terminal:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="My vcpkg location\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake"
```

and terminal showed:

```
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22000.0 to target Windows 10.0.22621.
CMake Error at C:/Users/Pei/Desktop/GitHub/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:853 (_find_package):
  By not providing "Findigraph.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "igraph", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "igraph" with any
  of the following names:

    igraphConfig.cmake
    igraph-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "igraph" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "igraph_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "igraph"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Usually for this error you do exactly what CMake told you to do.  Did you check to see if `igraphConfig.cmake` or `igraph-config.cmake` exists in your vcpkg folders?

Comment: Or run vcpkg in manifest mode. Cmake will invoke vcpkg and the package will be installed local to your project and configured for you.

Comment: Unrelated, but did you ever `set(igraph_test` to anything? What about `main`?

Comment: Please, do not **re-ask** a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76425832/cmake-cant-find-igraph-source-file) just because it has been closed. Editing the existing question and fixing the close reason is a proper way to go. In the new question you have posted old code of the previous question (with `${igraph_test}`).

Comment: As I said before, do not use `${igraph_test}`. You need to write `igraph_test`, as in the tutorial. Please cross-link threads, so readers are aware any prior discussion. https://igraph.discourse.group/t/using-cmake-and-find-configuring-incomplete-errors-occurred/1578/12